# How to correctly serve static files in django? on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

My static files work in DEBUG=True condition but in DEBUG=False it does not

My settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
#....
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL , document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

command I try
     python manage.py collectstatic
It create a folder but can not render the data

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %} # I try {% load static %} also
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app1css/home.css' %}">
      <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
     .</p>
     </body>
   </html>
```

This is my project structure

```
C:.
├───app1
│   ├───migrations
│       │   └───__pycache__
│           └───__pycache__
├───mysite
│   ├───static
│   │   └───app1css
│   └───__pycache__
├───static
│   ├───admin
│   │   ├───css
│   │   │   └───vendor
│   │   │       └───select2
│   │   ├───fonts
│   │   ├───img
│   │   │   └───gis
│   │   └───js
│   │       ├───admin
│   │       └───vendor
│   │           ├───jquery
│   │           ├───select2
│   │           │   └───i18n
│   │           └───xregexp
│   └───app1css
└───templates
    └───app
```

I have read many questions related to this but can not solve my problem. I have uploaded my blog to heroku with this setting(static files) but it give me SERVERERROR 500(debug=False). I have try to change {% load static %} to {% load staticfiles %} but still

django version 2.1.5
server apache 
python version 3.6.7

Comment: are you using `whitenoise` ?

Comment: I have install it  but not using

Comment: You should use it. Did you include it in your Middleware settings?. You should add `whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware` just below `SecurityMiddleware`. [Check the docs](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html)

Comment: yes it woks!! thank @Sergio and houzayfa rifai thank so much you guys save my life

Comment: One more question I have a portfolio app database- sqlite whenever I post my image on it it show for 1~2 days then automatically deleted this is my media root - 
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn', 'media_root')

Comment: Are you using Heroku's free tier? if so, files are stored only for a limited time, so for your data, you would need to use a postgresql database. [This guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment) provides the necessary steps to implement that. About the files, I'm afraid there is no way to store them in Herokus indefinitely (for the free tier).

Comment: Thank Sir thank so much